# python argcomplete and pyinstaller

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, pyinstaller

I have a problem with argcomplete script after I create bundle with pyinstaller. I generate sh from my script, use pyinstaller, copy it to /usr/bin change script complete command. And this isn't working, if I do this with py file, this works fine, where I do mistake? Or maybe this isn't possible to get with that script autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on myself, if someone will looking for that.

For global argcomplete it's simply just paste your bash script output from argcomplete to `/etc/bash_completion.d/<Your_sh_autocomplete_name>`

For local (user usage) argcomplete it requires two steps. Add file into `~/.bash_completion.d/<Your_sh_autocomplete_name>` and add source: `source ~/.bash_completion.d/<Your_sh_autocomplete_name>`. If it should autocomplete any time whenever you using bash shell, then command with source you can add to `~/.bashrc` file: `echo "source ~/.bash_completion.d/<Your_sh_autocomplete_name>" >> ~/.bashrc`.
And that's all, i missed for secound step when i want to do it local. So it isn't argcomplete or pyinstaller problem :)